# automate google response to display on google fusion map

Tags: forms, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I would like to create a form like below:

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1CO7Nj1Ehf_04kT54qCq96vRzAJsHJZQqBHVfUDJOVg8/edit

and of which the responses will be automatically display on Google Fusion Map as below:

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1I-TQio_yluZi5qjiXmA5nOBcCiTFDJyN5blkvGE#map:id=3

anyway to automate the responses from goolge form to display on google fusion map?

Comment: Were those supposed to be links?

Comment: sorry, didn't add the links properly.